# rails 4 iframe routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, iframe, coffeescript

I am following this [tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-coffeescript-in-rails/) just to learn more about implementing coffeescript.

My model is

```
class Url < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :url, presence: true

end
```

controller

```
class UrlsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @shortened_url = Url.new
  end

  def create
    @shortened_url = Url.new(url_params)
    if @shortened_url.save
      flash[:shortened_id] = @shortened_url.id
      redirect_to new_url_url
    else
      render :action => "new"
    end
  end

  def show
    @shortened_url = Url.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to @shortened_url.url

  end

  private

  def url_params

    params.require(:url).permit(:url)

  end
                                                                              end
```

end

coffeescript

```
$(document).ready ->
  preview = $("#preview-url")
  $('#url_url').keyup ->
    current_value = $.trim @value
    if current_value is ''
      preview.hide().attr 'src', ''
    else
      preview.show().attr 'src', current_value
```

app/views/layouts/application.rb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Shorty</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<% if flash[:shortened_id].present? %>
  <p class='shortened-link'>
    The shortened url is available <%= link_to 'here',
url_url(flash[:shortened_id]) %>.
    (Right click and copy link to share it).
  </p>
<% end %>


<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

app/views/urls/new.html.erb

```
<h1>Add a new URL</h1>
<%= form_for @shortened_url do |form| %>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :url, "Your URL:" %>
    <%= form.text_field :url %>
  </p>

  <% if @shortened_url.errors[:url].any? %>
    <p class='error-messages'>
      The given url <%= @shortened_url.errors[:url].to_sentence %>.
    </p>
  <% end %>

  <p class='buttons'>
    <%= form.submit "Shorten my URL" %>
  </p>

<% end %>

<iframe id='preview-url' style='width: 600px; height: 400px; display: none'></iframe>
```

config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :urls, :only => [:new, :show, :create]

 # get '/', to: 'urls#create', as: :new_url_url

  root :to => redirect('/urls/new')
end
```

the error is

No route matches [GET] "/urls/www.rte.ie"

I assume the coffeescript is being executed because the above address is the url I entered inthe text box and the iframe is invisible until an url is provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to add the protocol to the `url`, otherwise the redirect won't work when you do `redirect_to @shortened_url.url` in your `show` action. You can do that in your model with a `before_save` like this:

```
class Url < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :ensure_protocol

  private

  def ensure_protocol
    self.url = "http://#{url}" unless url_protocol_present?
  end

  def url_protocol_present?
    u = URI.parse(url)
    u.scheme
  end
end
```

Also, I think you have a typo in your `new` action: what is `new_url` in the `redirect_to` statement?

Comment: thanks, your answer fixed the saving of the url, it gave me an idea of how to fix the iframe issue, this amended coffeescript works

`$(document).ready ->
  preview = $("#preview-url")
  $('#url_url').keyup ->
    current_value ='http://' +  $.trim @value
    if current_value is ''
      preview.hide().attr 'src', ''
    else
      preview.show().attr 'src', current_value
`